# Entity query increments field value for every query (field is not autoincremented)

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity query that when I run increments the value of my field. I am using entity framework and sql server 2012. Here is my query;

```
public void GetLastAccountNumber(ProductLine productLine, Action completed)
        {
            EntityQuery query = WASMDomainContext.GetContactCustomerAccountsQuery()
                                                        .Where(cca => cca.ProductLineId == productLine.Id)
                                                        .OrderBy(cca => cca.AccountNumber);
            WASMDomainContext.Load(query, loadOp =>
            {
                Exception error = null;
                ContactCustomerAccount lastAccount = null;
                if (loadOp.HasError)
                    error = loadOp.Error;
                else
                    lastAccount = loadOp.Entities.LastOrDefault();
```

`// Invoke completion callback
            completed(lastAccount, error);
        }, null);
    }`

Query should return the last account number which is an integer field for now. However it returns an incremented value. For example in my table I have an accountnumber 0 the query returns an entity with account number as 1. My account number field is not auto increament and I find this very strange. And each time the above is called the AccountNumber field value increases by one but the database value will remain 0. I just want the query to return what is in my database. Any idea why this could be happening? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: Do not use all caps in titles.

Comment: pls show GetContactCustomerAccountsQuery and ContactCustomerAccount class declaration.